# Flutter Reset the properties of a PageRoute<T>

Tags: flutter, function, state

In flutter can you update the properties of `PageRoute<T>`. For example, if I want to change the `reverseTransitionDuration` property from `Duration(milliseconds: 300)` to `Duration(seconds: 1)` based on the press of a button in a sub widget, how can I set this property on the `PageRoute` or `ModalRoute` so that it updates / rebuilds the `PageRoute` to reflect this change.

Comment: It has been difficult to manage the overabundance of answers to all three ways I phrased this question over the last two weeks. The answer probably is that you can set almost anything you want in a PageRoute<T> but you need to extend it to provide the necessary method and set it's state directly inside that extension. I don't know for certain but logically that appears to be how it works. So no need for a parent inherited. Extend the PageRoute, create a new inherited widget to access it and execute any function you built in the extended PageRoute. Will post an answer if it works.